# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in OleDb vb.net

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Please give me a solution.

I think I made the query code wrong

```
Private Sub PopulateDataGridView()
    Dim query = "select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS FROM IFG (WHERE QOH > 0 AND ITM = @ITM OR ISNULL(@ITM, '') = '')"
    Dim constr As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=C:\Users\ADMIN2\Desktop; Extended Properties=dBase IV"
    Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITM", cbCountries.SelectedValue)
            Using sda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

[image: Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression]

[Syntax error in FROM clause.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6WKr.jpg)
[contents of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qod3A.jpg)

Comment: Still the error with the wrong number of arguments?

Comment: @djv , yes still error

Comment: @djv , if I omit all codes from and after "or isnull" then there is no error.

Comment: well that check is checking a parameter you're passing from your code so you can do that logic check in code instead of on the server

Comment: @djv I use a local database so not from the server. Tomorrow I will screenshot the contents of the database

Comment: @djv , I have a new question maybe you can help here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69475743/how-to-change-connection-string-oledb-path-to-current-desktop-user-path-in-vb -ne

Comment: I mean check in your code instead of the query. A local database is still hosted by a server (your own pc)

Comment: How does your logic work, can you update the query with proper parenthesis, as I mentioned in my answer? Or is it already correct? (WHERE 1 AND 2 OR 3)

Comment: @djv , I've added as you requested but error ("Syntax error in FROM clause."). I also attach screenshots of the contents of my database

Comment: Oh... well you took my comment literally, you don't put parenthes around the where that was just placed as an explanation. Remove the parenthesis

Comment: @djv ,can you edit your answer by removing the "isnull" sql statement so I mark the solution from your answer

Comment: I removed the "isnull" part of the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question about SQL syntax, really, and not so much vb.net or oledb.

You had two `WHERE` clauses, which is invalid SQL. Change the second `WHERE` to `AND`

```vb
Dim query As String = "select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS FROM IFG WHERE QOH > 0"
query &= " AND ITM = @ITM"
```

By the way, since strings are immutable in vb.net, you should not build a string like that (first assigning to, then adding to) when you so clearly can avoid it because every concatenation creates a new string in memory. You can either use `&`, a StringBuilder, or one long string. For example, taking advantage of vb.net syntax to make a multiline string, you can change the vb.net to

```vb
Dim query = "
select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS 
FROM IFG 
WHERE QOH > 0 
AND ITM = @ITM"
```

which is [subjectively] much easier to read as a SQL query (add the proper parentheses based on your logic, of course!).

Based on your update, you need to add a parameter to the query. Here is a more or less complete example of a query with one parameter

```vb
Using con As New OleDbConnection("connection string")
    Dim query = "
        select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS 
        FROM IFG 
        WHERE QOH > 0 
        AND ITM = @ITM"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITM", itmValue)
        Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            For Each result In rdr.AsQueryable()
                ' do something with each result
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: ,thanks for your reply, but there is an error. if I use full of your code then error "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression"

Comment: @roy see my edit

Comment: I add my code but still problem

Comment: @roy you will need to be more specific

Comment: I have updated my specific code

Comment: I have updated my full code in my posting